# Efficient IP address c/c++ library on unix

Tags: c++, python, c, freebsd, ipv6

Is there a good high level library that can be used for IP address manipulation? I need to do things like:

- Given a string find out if it is a valid IPv4/IPv6 address.
- Have functionality like ntop and pton
- etc

I can use the low level inet_ntop() etc. But is there a better library that handles these better and fast (c/c++/python)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by better?  What aspect of `inet_ntop()` and `inet_pton()` do you want to improve?

Comment: Are you saying you'll be processing huge batches of IP addresses and that's why you need it to be efficient? Or is the efficiency just a concern for the ntop aspect of actually probing the network?

Answer (score 3):

For C++, the standard high-level answer would be [boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/asio/index.html). Specifically, to convert a string into an IP address it has
[ip::address::from_string](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address/from_string.html) and to obtain a string representation of an ip address, it has [to_string](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address/to_string.html).

Do check out [other constructors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4/address_v4.html) for the ip address objects -- using raw bytes is likely to be more efficient than strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a sockets app it's highly unlikely that address manipulation is going to be your most important consideration.  Don't waste time on this when you have network I/O to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

`inet_ntop` and `inet_pton` do not support IPv6 zones and so the recommend APIs are simply `getaddrinfo` and `getnameinfo` which are conveniently IP version agnostic.

Pass flags such as `NI_NUMERICHOST` to force IP address validation without DNS resolution.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738532(VS.85).aspx

example:

```
char* input_str
struct addrinfo *result = NULL, hints;
ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
dwRetval = getaddrinfo( input_string, NULL, &hints, &result );
if ( dwRetval != 0 ) {
     /* failure */
}
```

Comment: Since this is about FreeBSD, one would simply look at the getaddrinfo(3) manpage, which has plenty of examples and does not include use of the ZeroMemory macro and properly defined constants PF_UNSPEC.

Comment: @Mel good point, no idea why I picked up on Windows Platform :/

Answer (score 0):

The [Poco Library](http://pocoproject.org/) has a very nice set of hostname/IP address manipulation routines, and a lot of other really great stuff.  The FreeBSD port is a bit out of date, but we might be able to poke the port-maintainer with a sharp stick and get him to update it.  Oh, wait... :)

Answer (score -1):

I have the mind boogling ipv4 / ipv6 validating regexps around, which are quite long and non-trivial to produce. I can share if you want.

Comment: Sorry to be uncharitable, but this answer amounts to "there is something that may be useful, somewhere in the world". I think the idea is to actually answer the question, giving some sort of actionable answer.